# Assigning values to a 2d array initiated in a struct causes an infinite loop

Tags: c, struct

```
typedef struct game_t {
    char gameBoard[ROWS][COLUMNS];
} Game;


Game* Create(){
    Game *thegame = (Game *)malloc(sizeof(Game*));
    if (thegame==NULL || historySize<=0){
        return NULL;
    }
    int row=0, col=0;
    for (row = 0; row<ROWS; row++){
        for (col = 0; col<COLUMNS; col++){
            thegame->gameBoard[row][col] = EMPTY_ENTRY;
        }
    }
    return thegame;
}
```

I'm trying to run the code above and to assign values to the 2d array initialized in the struct (capital letters are all #define values). for some reason, I keep entering into an infinite loop in eclipse. No flag is raised when I build the project, just when I run it.
Could anyone please explain to me what am I doing wrong?

thanks!

Comment: where is `ROWS` and `COLUMNS` defined?

Comment: How do you know its the loop? Confirm it by using a printf inside the loop

Comment: It's also possible to use `sizeof(*thegame)`.

Comment: Fyi, the `historySize` check should be done *before* you bother allocating at all, as this is recipe for a memory leak if you successfully allocate, but `historySize <=0` is true.

Comment: Do sizeof(Game) not its pointer

Comment: There is NO need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Answer (score 1):

Statement `Game *thegame = (Game *)malloc(sizeof(Game*))` is wrong for sure; together with `thegame->gameBoard[row][col] = EMPTY_ENTRY`, it introduces undefined behaviour, as you access memory that is not allocated. So you should write `Game *thegame = malloc(sizeof(Game))` instead. Note that in C, it is better *not* to cast the result of `malloc` as argued [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Anyway, if `EMPTY_ENTRY` is defined as value `0`, you could also use `calloc`, which initialises the memory with `0`. So you could omit your `for`-loops then (cf. [cppreference/calloc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc)):

> `void* calloc( size_t num, size_t size );` Allocates memory for an array
>   of `num` objects of size `size` and initializes all bytes in the allocated
>   storage to zero.

Comment: It is always worth noting that the cast of the return of `malloc` (or `calloc` or `realloc`) is unnecessary. See link in comment to original question. (I suspect you already know that, and that your inclusion is most likely due to simple copy/paste, but when answering, it is always better to clean that up.)

Comment: @David C. Rankin: right, thanks! Added your reference.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with the function.

First of all this statement

```
Game *thegame = (Game *)malloc(sizeof(Game*));
```

allocates memory with the size equal to the size of the pointer `Game*` instead of allocating memory with the size equal to the size of the structure `Game` or `struct game_t` that is the same.

You have to write

```
Game *thegame = (Game *)malloc(sizeof(Game));
```

or

```
Game *thegame = (Game *)malloc(sizeof(struct game_t));
```

The second problem is that there can be a memory leak in case when the variable `historySize` is less than or equal to 0.

Take into account that it is better to specify the function parameter as `void`.

The function definition can look the following way

```
Game * Create( void )
{
    Game *thegame = NULL;

    if ( historySize > 0 && ( thegame = malloc( sizeof( Game ) ) ) != NULL )
    { 
        for ( int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++ )
        {
            for ( int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++ )
            {
                thegame->gameBoard[row][col] = EMPTY_ENTRY;
            }
        }
    }

    return thegame;
}
```

Also it is not a good idea when a function deals with global variables. You could pass the variable `historySize` as an argument to the function.

In this case the function will look like (I suppose that the type of the variable `historySize` is `int`)

```
Game * Create( int  historySize )
{
    Game *thegame = NULL;

    if ( historySize > 0 && ( thegame = malloc( sizeof( Game ) ) ) != NULL )
    { 
        for ( int row = 0; row < ROWS; row++ )
        {
            for ( int col = 0; col < COLUMNS; col++ )
            {
                thegame->gameBoard[row][col] = EMPTY_ENTRY;
            }
        }
    }

    return thegame;
}
```

In this case the function can be called like

```
Create( historySize );
```

There is a possibility to substitute the loops for a call of the standard function `memset`.

For example

```
#include <string.h>

//...

Game * Create( int  historySize )
{
    Game *thegame = NULL;

    if ( historySize > 0 && ( thegame = malloc( sizeof( Game ) ) ) != NULL )
    {
        memset( thegame->gameBoard, EMPTY_ENTRY, ROWS * COLUMNS ); 
    }

    return thegame;
}
```

Comment: Good spotting on the second issue.

Comment: you've helped me a lot, really great advices.
thanks.